# Longest word in all languages

Tags: words

https://www.google.com/search?q=longest+word+in+all+languages&sxsrf=AOaemvKcePJS8wsKGqzL_U6e1NC7gQvzAg%3A1631976735337&source=hp&ei=H_1FYe7REZDn-QaKqY6ACQ&oq=longest+word+in+all+la&gs_lcp=ChFtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1ocBABGAAyBQgAEIAEMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46BwgjEOoCECc6DQguEMcBEK8BEOoCECc6BAgjECc6CAguEIAEELEDOgUIABCxAzoFCC4QgAQ6CAgAEIAEELEDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToLCC4QgAQQxwEQrwFQ50ZY6bkBYIzJAWgBcAB4AIABwQuIAchekgENMi01LjcuMi40LjMuMpgBAKABAbABDw&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-hp

Could there more than longest word as mentioned in the above link in all languages?

The pronunciation of the word becomes difficult as the word length increases.

Can we have a database of all longest words in all languages?

Tracing longest word/s in Arabic,French,Italian,German,Spanish,Dutch, Japanese etc.

Tracing longest word/s in Indian regional languages viz

Sanskrit, Hindi, Gujarati, Bengali and so on ...

Comment: Trivia about words is not part of linguistics, the scientific study of human language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we don't know what the longest words of all human languages are, we can't make a database of them, but we could start to accumulate proposed words, and then we'd append the disclaimer "as far as we know". There are at least three things you'd want to include in every entry: the language (using a standard language identifier), the word (however you represent it), and the length of the word. Words can have a number of different lengths: duration in milliseconds, number of bytes required in a fixed encoding, and number of "atomic written elements", something like "letter" only that isn't exactly the right word, given the variety of writing systems used. I suppose one could also measure the length in millimeters in a printed version at a given point size. One other problem is that many languages don't have uniform writing systems: some have two or more systems, some have none at all. Yet another possibility is to use "standard phonetic transcriptions" (where "th" as in "thin" is written as θ). The problem there is that transcription is a massively subjective enterprise, even for a language as simple as English.

Another problem is defining "word". In English, we conventionally use a space as an indicator that we have come to the end of the word, but not all languages do that. Sanskrit doesn't use spaces so everything looks like one gigantic word. There are often linguistic arguments that tell you that a sequence "αβγδ" is two words split between γ and δ, but often we spend forever debating whether such-and-such is one word.

An instance of that problem is that some language have very robust word-formation processes. For example there is a word in Shona [handizakazombodovabhururukisanirawo] meaning "I haven't ever gone and made them fly for each other (said politely)", where people often object "That's not a word, it's a sentence!". Big deal! English words are simple, Shona words are complex.

English has compound words like "lighthouse", "blackboard" which combine two words into one: do we count the combined word, or just the pieces. If "methionyl​...leucine" is one word, can we make compounds like "pre-methionyl​...leucine", "methionyl​...leucine-maker" and so on. Sanskrit compounds can be really ginormous. Languages of the Eskaleut family are famous for polysynthetic morphology, where huge numbers of suffixes can be added. The things that *they* can do with "methionyl​...leucine" are vastly longer than anything you can cook up in English. You might object that methionyl​...leucine is not a word of Central Alaskan Yupik, but by the same token it is not a word of English. You can analyze, and you can re-analyze, as well as  re-re-analyze and so on. Some languages have word formation processes which are unbounded, so there is no longest word.

In short, I'd say it's impossible because the question is not well-defined.

Comment: Thanks.
New Longest words can also be traced in all languages?